# Approximation quality of minimum k-cut

Tags: graph-theory, data-analysis, clustering

Can someone please clarify a point of confusion regarding approximate solutions to the minimum k-cut problem.

In the wiki page of [Minimum K-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut), it is stated that:

> *Several approximation algorithms exist with an approximation of*
>   $2-2/k.$

Other than the Gomory Hu tree based algorithm,  a simple greedy algorithm can be  found in page 7 [here](http://cs.gmu.edu/~lifei/teaching/cs684_spring12/multi-cut.pdf) which also has the approximation ratio $2-2/k$.

My question is: is this approximation factor respect to the optimal solution when $k$ is considered as fixed or when it is part of the input?

Answer (score 1):

In the slides that you refer to, it is stated that:

"The minimum k-cut problem is polynomial time solvable for fixed k;
however, it is NP-hard if k is specified as part of the input"

So yes, the approximation is only needed for the case when $k$ is part of the input.